# Why is this regex not selecting only the email addresses?

Tags: regex

RegExr example: http://regexr.com?333h5

Regex:

```
_email=(.+)[^\s"]
```

Sample Content:

```
http://example.com/index.php?package=icard&action=show_birthday_card&cid=3376&name=Gina&unsubscribe_email=myEmail1234@aol.com
[ Unsubscribe from iCard: http://example.com/index.php?package=icard&action=unsubscribe_card&unsubscribe_email=myEmail1234@aol.com ]


--1q2w3e4r5t6y7u8i9o0p1q
Content-Type: text/html;

<table align=""center"">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style=""background:#fff; border:10px solid #2d50d6; padding:10px; width:600px;"">
                <h4 style=""background:#2d50d6; color:#fff; border:18px solid #2d50d6; margin-bottom:10px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; text-align:center;"">Happy Birthday Gina!</h4>
                <a href=""http://example.com/index.php?package=icard&action=show_birthday_card&cid=3376&name=Gina&unsubscribe_email=myEmail1234@aol.com""><img src=""http://example.com/images/brands/chiro/cards/img_46a6924710bcc_birthdayparty.gif"" alt="""" title=""Happy+Birthday+Gina%21"" width=""600"" style=""border:0; margin-bottom:10px; width:600px; height:150px;"" /></a>
                <p style=""color:#000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;"">We hope all your birthday dreams and wishes come true!</p>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
_email=(.+)[^\s"]
```

Means "_email=" followed by 1-many characters of any type, followed by a single character that is neither whitespace nor a quote.

I think what you are looking for is:

```
_email=[^\s"]+
```

Which is "_email=" followed by 1-many characters that are neither whitespace nor a quote.

Answer (score 1):

This is selecting more than just the email addresses because the `+` is a greedy operator, and will attempt to match as many characters as possible.

Email address matching is a fairly common regex problem, as such there are many solutions with one included right in a great tutorial on [how to use regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).  I would recommend using one of these well tested patterns as such...

`_email=(\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b)`